# python: Undefined variable: __init__ error

Tags: python, eclipse

I'm trying to write a dummy program with python using eclipse and I get the error message: Undefined variable: `__init__`.

My aim is to Run the program with eclipse 'Run as' --> Python Run.

When I remove the code:

```
if __init__=='__main__': 
     main()
```

and run it from the command line say_something() - it works ok. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: love seeing more people using pydev :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're looking for `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Answer (score 7):

What you want there is:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`__init__` is the name of the class initialization function.